# Menu alignment - dropdown out of line with menu items

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am brand new to ASP.Net Core -- I literally started playing with it last night.

I am working on a website for a friend, and he requested a very specific layout for the menu bar at the top of the page:

Home | About | Books and Stories ▼ | Reviews | Other Projects

When I code what I think should be this functionality, I get this:

[image]

My code is here:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle text-dark" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Books and Stories <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu text-dark">
            <li><a asp-controller="BooksAndStories" asp-action="Novels">Novels</a></li>
            <li><a asp-controller="BooksAndStories" asp-action="Stories">Short Stories</a></li>
            <li><a asp-controller="BooksAndStories" asp-action="WIP">WIP</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Reviews" asp-action="Index">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="OtherProjects" asp-action="Index">About</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone provide me with some direction?  Google has been less than useful.

Thanks,

Carthax

Comment: this is not problem asp.net-core but UI so html and css. Check if your carret class hasn't bigger height than your other menu elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify `.dropdown-toggle` in bootstrap.css file under `wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/css` like below:

```
.dropdown-toggle {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
```

Comment: You rock on with your bad self.  That's perfect!  Thanks!

Comment: @Carthax , If you find my solution works , could you mark my reply as answer ? This will help others who may have the same question to find the answer quickly.

Comment: Sorry; I forgot to do that.  Done.